# Set refresh rate to 60Hz - Before Windows boots up

Tags: laptop, display, refresh-rate

A while ago my laptop display started acting up, flickering and showing lots of lines, not showing the screen occasionally, etc. I found the solution is to set the refresh rate to 60Hz (instead of 144Hz). If I try to set it back to 144Hz, I don't see anything other than some white lines at the middle top of the display, but fortunately it goes back automatically to 60Hz after about 10-15 seconds.

The real problem is that during booting I also don't see anything except for those white lines. It's fine when Windows boots up, but I'm very scared something will happen which will boot the computer to BIOS or some troubleshooting screen. I suppose I won't be able to see the display in that case.
I tried connecting the display to an external display once, but it didn't work.

I was wondering if I could set the refresh rate of the display itself to 60Hz, so that it will be at 60Hz constantly, even it is in BIOS. Is that possible? Maybe with regedit/registry?

Thank you!

Comment: What model is your monitor (or laptop if it's built-in) ?

Comment: @harrymc ASUS TUF A15, model number FA506IU

Comment: Try to update the BIOS. The [latest version](https://www.asus.com/laptops/for-gaming/tuf-gaming/asus-tuf-gaming-a15-2022/helpdesk_bios?model2Name=ASUS-TUF-Gaming-A15-2022) seems to be from 2023/04/14. I would suggest to use the ASUS EZ Flash Utility for safety.

Comment: How would that help? What does this have hardcoding the refresh rate into the monitor? Also, I'm afraid it would boot into the BIOS which means I probably won't see the screen.

Comment: Setting the refresh rate is only possible if the monitor has an on-screen OSD. Otherwise, improving the BIOS seems the only other possibility (besides giving up).

Answer (score 1):

There is *nothing* in Windows operating system (OS), whether in the Registry or elsewhere, that affects what one sees in BIOS/UEFI setup. At that time, the OS is not even *selected*, much less started.

However, output in BIOS setup is often for the lowest common display, e.g., 60 Hz, 1366 x 768, so that it can be adjusted on almost *any* device. You could test that *safely* by [entering BIOS setup](https://www.manualowl.com/m/Asus/TUF-Gaming-A15/Manual/559057?page=65): even if the display is blank, pressing <kbd>F10</kbd> will continue to a normal Windows boot.

If BIOS display works, press <kbd>F7</kbd> for *Advanced* features, and, on the *Display configuration* screen, set refresh rate appropriately, if that's available on your BIOS version.

That said, this gradual display failure appears to be a hardware issue that needs to be addressed. Try upgrading BIOS version, but don't be too sanguine that it will fix the issue.